# How to remove a dynamically created node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating a simple shopping cart web page in Javascript as a homework assignment. I am creating a "remove item" button for each book that is in the shopping cart, but I can't quite figure out how to implement it. I know it will require use of the DOM tree, but I don't understand how. Here is the relevant code:

```
<script>

function addToCart(bookToAdd, priceToAdd)
{
    //Create the node
    var bookInfo = document.createElement();
    bookInfoString = "Book: " + document.getElementById(bookToAdd).innerHTML + 
        " <br />Price: $" + document.getElementById(priceToAdd).innerHTML + 
        '<br /> <button type="button" onclick="removeFromCart(' + bookToAdd + ', ' + priceToAdd + ')">Remove from cart!</button> <br /> <br />';
    bookInfo.innerHTML = bookInfoString;
    //Append the node
    document.getElementById('cartItems').appendChild(bookInfo); 
    //Update the cart total
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').firstChild.nodeValue = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById(priceToAdd).innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
}

function removeFromCart(bookToRemove, priceToRemove)
{
    //Remove the node
    getElementById('cartItems').removeChild(bookToRemove);
    //Update the cart total
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').firstChild.nodeValue = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML) - parseFloat(document.getElementById(priceToRemove).innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
}

</script>
```

... A relavant part of the html code:

```
    <tr>
        <!--Fill in the first book information-->
        <td> <span class="bookName" id="book1"><b>Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach</b></span><br>
        <img src="AI.jpeg" alt="AI Book Cover" width="100"> <br>
        <b>ISBN:</b> 978-0-13-604259-4 <br>
        <b>Description:</b> Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, 3e offers the most comprehensive, 
        up-to-date introduction to the theory and practice of artificial intelligence. Number one in 
        its field, this textbook is ideal for one or two-semester, undergraduate or graduate-level 
        courses in Artificial Intelligence. <br>
        <b>PRICE: $</b> <span id="price1"> 158.55 </span> 
        <button type="button" onclick="addToCart('book1', 'price1')">Add to cart!</button>
        </td>

        <!-- Create the shopping cart area of the page-->
        <td rowspan="10"> 
        <!-- Create the space for the items in the cart to be written -->
        <div id="cartItems"></div>

        <!-- Create the space for the Total Price to be written -->
        <b>Total Price: $<div style="display: inline" id="totalPrice">0</div></b>
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Everything works apart from deleting an entry; I am specifically having a hard time figuring out how to access the specific node that needs to be deleted; all of the entries in the shopping cart that are for the Artificial Intelligence book I showed above were created with the same id ('book1'), so I don't know how to single one out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 9 other books that can be added by the way; the shopping cart is a little more interesting than having only 1 item. :)

Comment: How do I give it a unique ID if I'm creating it dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - I give it a unigue ID, but do not really need it since I remove the parentNode instead

```
function addToCart(bookToAdd, priceToAdd) {
    //Create the node
    var bookInfo = document.createElement("div");
    bookInfoString = "Book: " + document.getElementById(bookToAdd).innerHTML + 
        " <br />Price: $" + document.getElementById(priceToAdd).innerHTML + 
        '<br /> <button type="button" onclick="removeFromCart(this.parentNode,'+ 
         priceToAdd + ')">Remove from cart!</button> <br /> <br />';
    bookInfo.innerHTML = bookInfoString;
    bookInfo.id=bookToAdd+'_'+new Date().getTime();
    //Append the node
    document.getElementById('cartItems').appendChild(bookInfo); 
    //Update the cart total
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById(priceToAdd).innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
}

function removeFromCart(bookToRemove, priceToRemove) {
    //Remove the node
    getElementById('cartItems').removeChild(bookToRemove);
    //Update the cart total
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML) - parseFloat(document.getElementById(priceToRemove).innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Elaborate? Errors in the console, nothing?

Comment: I had fixed it, and your answer provided some insight. I don't remember the particulars now :p